# Parse JavaScript array with empty elements using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this javascript element using BS4.
I want to get that input array into a usable format.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
        require.config.params['matchheader'] = {
            input: [162,13,'Crystal Palace','Arsenal','05/08/2022 20:00:00','05/08/2022 00:00:00',6,'FT','0 : 1','0 : 2',,,'0 : 2','England','England']
    ,
            matchId: 1640674
        };


</script>
```

To get the text inside the global variable, I used the following regex:

```
re.search("input: \[.*?\]", script_element.string).group(0)
```

which returns:

```
"input: [162,13,'Crystal Palace','Arsenal','05/08/2022 20:00:00','05/08/2022 00:00:00',6,'FT','0 : 1','0 : 2',,,'0 : 2','England','England']"
```

I am having some trouble parsing this array because of the empty elements (`literal_eval` does not work).

Any idea on how to accomplish this? Is there an easier way to do it?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be insert `None` between the empty `,` and then parse it:

```py
import re
from ast import literal_eval

data = re.search(r"input:\s*(.*)", s).group(1)  # <-- `s` is your string from the question
data = re.sub(r"(?<=,)\s*(?=,)", "None", data)
data = literal_eval(data)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
[162, 13, 'Crystal Palace', 'Arsenal', '05/08/2022 20:00:00', '05/08/2022 00:00:00', 6, 'FT', '0 : 1', '0 : 2', None, None, '0 : 2', 'England', 'England']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do some string manipulation and do a `.split(',')` on the string to create a list.

```
import re

var_to_parse = """
<script type="text/javascript">
    
        require.config.params['matchheader'] = {
            input: [162,13,'Crystal Palace','Arsenal','05/08/2022 20:00:00','05/08/2022 00:00:00',6,'FT','0 : 1','0 : 2',,,'0 : 2','England','England']
    ,
            matchId: 1640674
        };


</script>
"""
parse1 = re.search("input: \[.*?\]", var_to_parse).group(0)
parse2 = parse1.split("input: ")[1]
parse3 = parse2[1:-1]
parse4 = parse3.split(',')
print("parse4:", parse4)
```